# How to make a Katana handle Pattern with array?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, extrude

[image: Katana In Question]

Hi,this is my first time using this website.I was wondering on how to make the pattern on the katana handle above. The gold ovals are lower into the handle than the rest of the handle, when I try to recreate this in blender it works fine. I just extrude the faces on both sides and it starts to look alright. But when I try to array it, it goes inside of cylinder(handle). How do I make it so that the cylinder also extrudes in. I can do it all individually but I really don't want to. I'm very new to blender(1.5 weeks) so the answer is probably very obvious lol. Thanks!

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21167/twist-rope-around-an-object https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/92757/how-to-model-apply-a-rhomboid-pattern-on-a-cylinder-sword-hilt-modeling https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/235074/creating-diagonal-loop-cuts-in-a-cylinder https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/95381/how-to-detail-my-sword-texture

Comment: This question seems to have already been asked in various forms over time and already has a multiple answers, but you never acknowledged any of the existing posts. We are not sure if you aware of them but none of the described techniques fulfil your particular requisites, or you simply didn't do any research at all. Could you [edit] you post and clarify how your question differs from the suggested duplicates? Otherwise could you rephrase it to focus on a particular step you are stuck with?